# Is Lana's "Yup!" a triphthong?

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics, phonetics, vowels, triphthongs

At some point in the Archer series, Lana starts saying very emphatic [Yup!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQkxJ4WcXjA)s. I was recently wondering about triphthongs and whether they occur in English, and found the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphthong#English) had only a few examples, in the British Received Pronunciation and Cockney, which led me to believe they don't occur so often in English.

Are Lana's [Yup!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQkxJ4WcXjA)s examples of triphthongs (**i - u - a** - P)? Particularly the one around 0:05, when she's in the car with Cyril, where it even sounds like a quadthong (**i - u - o - a** - P)?

Comment: I can't tell you about tripthongs since she seems be fully clothed in those excerpts, but it seems like a simple affected "yup" to me -- apparently her trademark.  It's not at all unusual for an normal English speaker to use an elongated "yeeeesss" or maybe pronounce "Cyril" as "Sihhhh-reaaaal" for emphasis.  It does not change the meanings of the words (other than what emphasis normally does) and does not constitute a different dialect.  (Though certainly some dialects do such things all the time vs only for emphasis.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Ah yes, triphthong =P. I don't expect it would change the meaning of the word or constitute a different dialect, I was just curious whether the way she emphasized this word constituted a triphthong. Wouldn't an affected/emphasized vowel sound which involves a quick but smooth movement of the articulator from one vowel quality to another that passes over a third constitute a triphthong?

Comment: A vowel sequence has to be all in the same syllable to be an X-phthong.

Comment: @tchrist: ah of course. Yet these clearly appear to me to be in different syllables. That makes sense!